# Conditinal Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, machine-learning

In the pattern recognition and machine learning book by Christopher Bishop, page 73, eq:2.19, we have that for a given i.i.d data set $D$ that are realizations of a random variable $X$ whose probability density function is parameterized with a random variable $\mu$
\begin{equation}
p(x|D) = \int_0^1 p(x|\mu)p(\mu|D)\,\textrm{d}\mu = \int_0^1 \mu p(\mu|D)\,\textrm{d}\mu
\end{equation}
I have been struggling to show the steps in getting the two equalities above. Would someone please help in concisely showing the intermediate steps with their assumptions?

Comment: Needs more information on exactly *how* the density function is parameterised with $\mu$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the book, it seems to be because $x\sim \text{Bern}(\mu)$ and $\mu\sim \beta(a,b)$.

Then:
\begin{align*}
P(x=1|D) &= \int\limits_0^1 P(x=1|D,\mu) \, P(\mu|D)\,d\mu\\
         &= \int\limits_0^1 P(x=1|\mu)\, P(\mu|D)\,d\mu\\
         &= \int\limits_0^1 \mu P(\mu|D)\,d\mu\\[1mm]
         &= \mathbb{E}[\mu|D]
\end{align*}
where

- The first step uses the law of total probability (applied to a conditional probability)
- The second step is because $x$ only depends on $D$ through $\mu$ (by assumption)
- The third is  because $x\sim \text{Bern}(\mu)$ and thus by the definition of the $\mu$ parameter
- The last step is by the definition of conditional expectation

Hopefully I read it correctly!